# Unit Test of void method with private fields - Line Coverage

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, easymock

I have the following code in my `void` method in `ClassUnderTest` class

```
public void doSomething(){

    A a = new A();
    a.setAb("b");
    a.setAc("c");

    persistantObject.commitObj(a);
}
```

I know how to write a passing JUnit, however, I can't figure out how to get a 100% line coverage.

I've attempted the following

```
@Mock
private PersistantObject mockPersistantObject;
public void testDoSomething(){

    EasyMock.createMock(this);
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classUnderTest, "persistantObject", mockPersistantObject);

    A a = new A();
    a.setAb("b");
    a.setAc("c");

    mockPersistantObject.commitObj(a);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();

    EasyMock.replay(this);
    classUnderTest.doSomething();
    ...
    EasyMock.verify(this);
}
```

Comment: You just want your `doSomething` method to have 100% line coverage?

Comment: you got it brother! yes! and possibly the PIT coverage too!

Comment: I did some coding here and I am getting 100% line coverage of `doSomething` method here. What line is not covered in your test?

Answer (score 0):

UnitTesting is **not** about *line* coverage.

UnitTesting is about *requirement* coverage.

Line coverage is just a tool to get a feeling about how much of the *requirements* already implemented might be covered.

So don't care too much about the LoCs covered by your test but look for *behavior* in your *requirements*, that needs a certain *behavior* of your cut and check if that is covered by a test.

---

Furthermore UnitTests do not care about LoCs for another reason: The LoCs are subject to change during refactoring and evolving the application. Therefore any effort you may do to increase the line coverage will either lead to breaking test or prevent the required changes (depending on your confidence in your tests and or your skills). But Unittests should only fail if the *behavior* changes, not the code implementing it.

Comment: Yes..The Jenkins build is setup so that the Junits checked in would have to pass a certain line AND PIT mutation coverage. This requirement is coming from the DevOps, not me!

Comment: *"have to pass a certain line AND PIT mutation coverage. This requirement is coming from the DevOps"* What is the value they expect? I found that you can easily get 85%+ by doing TDD.

Comment: "85%+" do you mean LoC or PIT? The method code is fairly large and has already been implemented way in advance. I'm trying to add the JUnit to it. Is there a more straight forward solution to this problem other than re-doing the work?

Comment: You surely have to *refactor* the code to apply *single responsibility* and *same level of abstraction* introducing new objects (to be injected as dependencies) that either do some primitive calculations or call methods on other objects (not both at the same time). You can use the *automated refactorings* of your  IDE to do that. And it will also improve extensibility and reusability of the cut.